# libz compress fails if saving data

Tags: c++, zlib

I've just encountered quite a strange behavior of *libz*. If I just use **compress** function everything works fine but if I try to eg. save compressed data to file I get **Z_BUF_ERROR**. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "zlib.h"

typedef unsigned char byte_t;

static int read_filesize(const char* filename) {
    int size = -1;
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file.is_open()) return size;

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size = (int) file.tellg();
    file.close();

    return size;
}

static bool read_binary_file(const char* filename, byte_t* dst, const unsigned length) {
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) return false;

    file.read((char*) dst, length);
    file.close();

    return true;
}

static bool save_binary_file(const char* filename, const byte_t* src, const unsigned length) {
    std::ofstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) return false;

    file.write((const char*) src, length);
    file.close();

    return true;
}

int main(int args, char **argv) {
    int fileSize = read_filesize(argv[1]);
    byte_t fileData[fileSize];
    bool result = read_binary_file(argv[1], fileData, fileSize);

    unsigned compressedSize = compressBound(fileSize);
    byte_t compressed[compressedSize]; 

    int compressionResult = compress(compressed, (unsigned long*) &compressedSize, fileData, fileSize);

    switch (compressionResult) {
    case Z_OK:
        std::cout << "Compression succeeded!\n";
        break;

    case Z_MEM_ERROR:
        std::cout << "Error: Z_MEM_ERROR!\n";
        return 1;

    case Z_BUF_ERROR:
        std::cout << "Error: Z_BUF_ERROR!\n";
        return 1;

    default:
        std::cout << "Error: UNDEFINED!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Size of '" << argv[1] << "': " << fileSize << "\n"
            << "After: " << compressedSize << "\n";

    bool saveResult = save_binary_file("file.bin.z", compressed, compressedSize);  // everything works if I remove this instruction

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What **C++** compiler are you using that allows VLAs ? (`byte_t fileData[fileSize];`)

Comment: @WhozCraig I use *g++ 4.8.2*

Comment: No kidding? I wasn't aware. thanks for the info.

Comment: @WhozCraig: IIRC, these are not VLA, like in C99, but standard arrays with non-const sizes, an older GCC/G++ extension, and incompatibles with VLAs in suble ways.

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but in a 64-bit Linux, the type `unsigned long` is 64-bits, while `unsigned` is 32-bits. So your cast `(unsigned long*) &compressedSize` renders Undefined Behaviour. If you use Windows or Linux-32, then you are (totally non portable but) safe.

Comment: @rodrigo That was an issue, please create an answar so that I can reward you :)

Comment: @Robin92: Ok! I've just added that as an answer.

Comment: @rodrigo So they're not variable length arrays; they're regular arrays with non-const (i.e. *variable*) length? Why didn't I see that? Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments above seems that you are using a 64-bit architecture where `sizeof(unsigned long)==8`, while `sizeof(unsigned)==4`.

Thus, the cast `(unsigned long*)&compressedSize` where `compressedSize` is of type `unsigned`, produces Undefined Behaviour.

Just changing the declaration of `compressedSize` to type `unsigned long` should fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow? I don't know how dynamic arrays are implemented in g++, but if they are put on the stack, you may have problems with large files. Use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: What that has to do with my issue? I know about stack's restrictions so I test this code on it's source (~ 1 kB), which I assure you is not a problem on my system.

Answer (score 0):

```
int fileSize = read_filesize(argv[1]);
byte_t fileData[fileSize];
```

It s a VLA (variable length array). They shall not be used. use std::vector instead.
Same thing applies for `compressed`